# Error input shape of MNIST using InceptionV3

Tags: python, image, keras

I'm trying to use MNIST images with many classifier but for some reason now it produces this error. (before was correct but I've change the sources of InceptionV3).
This is the error provided:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs)
   1627  try:
-> 1628     c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
   1629   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_6a/Branch_0/Conv2d_1a_1x1/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,1,288], [3,3,288,384].
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-db92b294fe8d> in <module>
----> 1 fileImg1.play("Saliency")

~\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\cexplainer\src\Xlib.py in play(self, ex)
    193         if (ex not in self.dictImgModel):
    194             explainer = self.dictImgExplainer[ex]
--> 195             img = prepareImage(self.name,self.PATH,self.SHAPE_1,self.SHAPE_2,self.dataset,self.X_vec,self.y_vec,explainer,label)
    196             self.dictImgModel[ex] = img
    197 

~\OneDrive\Documenti\GitHub\cexplainer\src\algorithms\KDD.py in prepareImage(name, PATH, SHAPE_1, SHAPE_2, dataset, X_vec, y_vec, explainer, label)
    438                 with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v3_arg_scope()):
    439                     _, end_points = inception.inception_v3(processed_images, is_training=False,
--> 440                                                               num_classes=10)
    441                     # Restore the checkpoint
    442                     sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\slim\python\slim\nets\inception_v3.py in inception_v3(inputs, num_classes, is_training, dropout_keep_prob, min_depth, depth_multiplier, prediction_fn, spatial_squeeze, reuse, scope)
    578           scope=scope,
    579           min_depth=min_depth,
--> 580           depth_multiplier=depth_multiplier)
    581 
    582       # Auxiliary Head logits
```

Some advice?

Comment: Definitely something wrong with the shapes: `input shapes: [?,1,1,288], [3,3,288,384]`. Fix your input shape and should be fine. Otherwise in case you are using a trained model, you might need to re-define the `Input` layer . Should be one of those 2 issues.

Comment: You probably need to shuffle the dimensions as well, since the channel dimensions are placed different in the 2 shapes. Also, looks like you need 3 channels. Copy your channels.

Answer (score 0):

MNIST is a collection of 1 channel images. All pre-trained models use 3-channels (rgb) images. You can bypass this conflict by repeating 3 times your single channel images.